# NuGet - Package Manager Not Connecting to Remote Server

Tags: database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, nuget

In Visual Studio 2012 I try clicking the "Manage NuGet Packages..." option on a project and when the package manager opens it tries to load for a while before giving me "Unable to connect to remote server".

There is a similar question here: [Visual Studio/C#: Nuget Unable to connect to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553591/nuget-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server)
but it doesn't appear to have any answer that I can see.

I have tried updating Visual Studio 2012 as well as updating NuGet (the "Extensions and Updates" option still works just fine) and then restarting but no such luck. It was working earlier, but I have since created a new database connection using the Database Explorer. I don't know if that would affect anything but that's the only change I could think of that I've made since it was working.

Please let me know if you need any other information.

**Edit:** Okay so apparently this fixes itself after a while. But only AFTER you've submitted a question about it... sigh. I'd still like to know what the issue is if anyone has any idea, but at least it's working now.

Comment: Did you try that just one hour ago? Nuget.org was down...

Comment: There's is/was an outage of NuGet at the time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

While you could certainly [access the cached packages on your own machine](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx), if you're working in a team you could install [ProGet](http://inedo.com/proget) as an intermediary NuGet server, and it will automatically cache the remote packages on your network for your team.