# EXEC: Unable to connect to the remote server on NuGet restore on TFS build server

Tags: tfs, nuget

I am trying to use NuGet restore to pull the packages on the TFS build process, however, it keeps giving out the error **EXEC: Unable to connect to the remote server**

If I manually execute the MsBuild MyProjet.sln, it will build without issues.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nuget Unable to connect to remote server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553591/nuget-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server)

Comment: yes, I see that question, but it seems to be a different issue. I was able to execute the whole build process from the command line, however, I was not able to run it in the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that TFS service is running at a different account than my own account. After log on as the TFS account and turned on proxy server for that account, NuGet is able to download the package and finish the build.