# Nuget Error - Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I know there are many links with this but none of them helped me. I am getting "Unable to connect to the remote server" message.

Below are the things I tried based on the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553591/nuget-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server)

1. Cleared HTTP_PROXY
2. Unchecked "act as system proxy on startup" in fiddler.
3. Cleared package cache.
4. Restarted VS
5. Deleted .suo file and restarted VS

But nothing worked. Any thoughts?

Comment: may be some links, ports are blocking in firewall, install the fiddler and check the underline links and port are connecting. Provide those info to your network administrator he will take care the test.

Comment: Can you list the packages, when using Nuget Package Explorer ? (https://npe.codeplex.com/)  and also: is it the nuget.org server, or a self-hosted server?

Answer (score 0):

Check if all NuGet server in your NUGetserver list are online. I found out that Visual Studio connected also other servers that I Selected (With Fiddler). After I removed the NuGetServer that was not online from the list, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions as well, in the end, I believe the issue is that, for whatever reason, my network administrator blocked the "source" url for Nuget.  The only thing that worked for me was to download the library packages from the Nuget website, and use them locally... this required using a computer on a different network, saving the libraries to a thumb-drive, and transferring them onto the desired computer.

Step 1> Download Libraries to a local folder

Step 2> Add the path of the local folder to the Nuget package sources in Visual Studio. This is done by navigating to Tools>>Nuget Package Manager >> Package Manager Settings >> Package Sources. Then, click the green "Plus" sign and type in the local path in the "Source Dialogue Box" (e.g. C:\LocalNugetLibrary, or whatever). Give it a name like "Local Library"

Step 3> Add the library like you normally would in Visual Studio. Right click on "References" in the solution explorer, then Manage Nuget Packages, then on the left side of the window click on your online source "Local Library"

Step 4> Click on the library you want to install

Done

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet Package Manager error, **Unable to connect to remote server** is typically a DNS name resolution issue. It was strange for me because I had no problem with name resolution in any other applications including IE and Chrome. I realize this is an old thread but this issue was plaguing me for quite some time in multiple versions of Visual Studio including 2017. I just recently realized that I had disabled the "DNS Client" service on my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop at some point in the past to reduce the number of Windows services competing for resources. Re-enabling the "DNS Client" service resolved my issue. Hopefully this will help save someone else some time and frustration.