# Jenkins unable to download xamarin dependency from dl.google.com / maven.google.com

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget

Jenkins unable to download xamarin dependency  from dl.google.com / maven.google.com

*Download failure reason: Unable to connect to the remote server*

**Project stack**
 Dotnet Xamarin android application

**Error**

```html
 Downloading https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.1/firebase-core-16.0.1.aar to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\googlefb-16.0.1/firebasecore.aar
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.8.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(52,3): error XBD001: Download failed. Please download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-core/16.0.1/firebase-core-16.0.1.aar to a file called C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\googlefb-16.0.1/firebasecore.aar. [D:\myfolder\Jenkins\workspace\projectname\project\project.Android\project.Android.csproj]
  Download failure reason: Unable to connect to the remote server
    Downloading https://maven.google.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.6.3/crashlytics-core-2.6.3.aar to C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlyticscore-2.6.3.aar
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.8.0\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.targets(52,3): error XBD001: Download failed. Please download https://maven.google.com/com/crashlytics/sdk/android/crashlytics-core/2.6.3/crashlytics-core-2.6.3.aar to a file called C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache\crashlyticscore-2.6.3.aar. [D:\myfolder\Jenkins\workspace\projectname\project\project.Android\project.Android.csproj]
  Download failure reason: Unable to connect to the remote server
```

I have tried configured corporate proxy in Jenkins. it works on the proxy configuration page but throws an error while building code. See in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hack work around. Download them yourself on your machine and put them in the gradle cache of the CI machine? :-)

Comment: thanks for your response @Blundell , but it is related to NuGet dependency nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Crashlytics

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553591/visual-studio-c-nuget-unable-to-connect-to-remote-server

Comment: thanks, @sermet I already did all the workaround stuff which is given in the above link. But not helpful to me.